# HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables throws null reference exception in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, httpcontext

I have used HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["server_name"] to get the hostname in my mvc application. It throws an exception as follows: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".   Having this line in my controller.                                                       string serverHost = Helper.GetHost();      And Having this method  in my helper class. accessed this method from my controller. Not an controller constructor.                                 public static string GetHost()
        {
            var url = string.Empty;
            var ipaddress = string.Empty;
            var sslFlag = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ssl"];
            var iisFlag = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["iis"];
            if (iisFlag.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                ipaddress = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IpAddress"];
            else
                ipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

```
        if (sslFlag.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            url = "https://";
        else
            url = "http://";
        return url + ipaddress;
    } Please let me know how to resolve the issue and suggest me a solution to get the hostname and port number in c#. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Where are you using this??

Comment: I have used it in the Helper.cs class file and invoked the method from the controller.

Comment: Using it in Controller Constructor ??

Comment: string serverHost = Helper.GetHost();

Comment: you mean its a field..in controller...not inside action method..

Comment: yes Abdul Khan. Its a field in the controller.Its not inside the action method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    string serverHost = Helper.GetHost();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var t = serverHost;
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GetHost() { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["server_name"]; }
}
```

This simple Code in my Dummy Application Works.